# What is average_loss field in Caffe solver for?

Tags: caffe

What is the use for `average_loss`? Would someone please give an example of it or explain it in layman's terms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check in the [caffe.proto](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto) file. Line 151 in the present version gives the following comment for average_loss:

```
Display the loss averaged over the last average_loss iterations
```

Comment: so what does that mean exactly?
what does averaging loss for x iteration do? just averaging and displaying it ? why would I want that?

Comment: Instead of the complete average loss. It gives you the loss for the last n iterations. It's just a feature. Might be useful in some networks.

Comment: Thanks, though it would be very desirable to know an intuitive example for it

Comment: Sometimes training is performed with a small batch size and the loss might be noisy. It makes sense to average it over last n iterations to get a better understanding of what is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense