# Does tensorflow provide an operation like caffe average_loss operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe, semantic-segmentation

due to the limiting of gpu, I want to update my weight after every two step training. Specifically, the network will firstly calculate the fisrt batch inputs and save the loss. And then the network calculate the next batch inputs and average these two losses and will update the weights once. It likes average_loss op in caffe, for example()[fcn-berkeley](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn8s/solver.prototxt) . and how to calculate the batchnorm update-ops.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190377/what-is-average-loss-field-in-caffe-solver-for) thread for correct info on Caffe's `average_loss`.

You should be able to compute an averaged loss by subclassing [LoggingTensorHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/LoggingTensorHook) in a way like

```
class MyLoggingTensorHook(tf.train.LoggingTensorHook):

    # set every_n_iter to if you want to average last 2 losses
    def __init__(self, tensors, every_n_iter):
        super().__init__(tensors=tensors, every_n_iter=every_n_iter)

        # keep track of previous losses
        self.losses=[]

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        _ = run_context

        # assuming you have a tag like 'average_loss'
        # as the name of your loss tensor
        for tag in self._tag_order:
            if 'average_loss' in tag:
                self.losses.append(run_values.results[tag])

        if self._should_trigger:
            self._log_tensors(run_values.results)

        self._iter_count += 1

    def _log_tensors(self, tensor_values):

        original = np.get_printoptions()
        np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
        logging.info("%s = %s" % ('average_loss', np.mean(self.losses)))
        np.set_printoptions(**original)
        self.losses=[]
```

and attach it to an estimator's [train](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#train) method or use a [TrainSpec](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/TrainSpec).

You should be able to compute gradients of your variables normally in every step, but apply them in every N steps by conditioning on your `global_state` variable that defines your current iteration or step (you should have initialized this variable in your graph by something like `global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()`). Please see the usage of [compute_gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients) and [apply_gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#apply_gradients) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, juste use `tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor)`

[Tf documentation reduce_mean](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_mean)

and in your case, it will be :

```
loss = tf.concat([loss1,loss2], axis=0)

final_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=0)
```